# Oracle: return rows in JSON format?

Tags: json, oracle

Is there a way to tell Oracle to return rows from a query in the form of a JSON string?

For example,

```
select 11,'abc' from dual;
```

would return

```
[11,"abc"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no simple function, no. There is [PL/JSON](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/) at Sourceforge. Also, this [ORA-0001](http://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2010/02/ref-cursor-to-json.html) blog post demonstrates a method using XML (way down the page).

Comment: The ORA-0001 method looks like it does just the right thing.  Thanks!